# How to change the color of the title in title bar

Tags: sencha-touch, themes, sencha-touch-2

In my application, i am trying to change the color of the title. For that, i put some themes in app.scss file. I am able to change the background color of the title bar. But color of the title is not changing. My app.scss file is like this:

```
    $base-color: #588aad; // go big blue!$include_default_icons: false;
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';
@include sencha-panel;
@include sencha-buttons;
@include sencha-sheet;
@include sencha-picker;
@include sencha-tabs;
@include sencha-toolbar;
@include sencha-toolbar-forms;
@include sencha-indexbar;
@include sencha-list;
@include sencha-layout;
@include sencha-form;
@include sencha-msgbox;
@include sencha-loading-spinner;


@include pictos-iconmask("bookmarks");
@include pictos-iconmask("compose");
@include pictos-iconmask("trash");
@include pictos-iconmask("search");
@include pictos-iconmask("bookmark2");


@include sencha-toolbar-ui('blue', #EEEEEE,'matte');
.x-toolbar .x-toolbar-title {
    color: #5a3d23;
}
```

And this is my panel code:

```
  Ext.define('MyApp.view.TitlePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    config: {
        modal: false,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'top',
                height: 120,
                ui: 'blue',
                title: 'Teritree Bussiness Portal',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'image',
                        docked: 'left',
                        height: 118,
                        width: 202,
                        src: 'resources/images/Logo.PNG'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

Can any one please help???
Thanks in advance..

Comment: just use Google Chrome debugger tool to inspect the CSS property that affects the color of that title and override it with `!important`

Comment: No error i am getting in the chrome debuger

Comment: that's not an error, I mean the CSS inspector

Comment: element.style {
width: 100% !important;
height: 100% !important;
}                                                                       Are you talking about this??

Comment: inspect that title of the toolbar and see what is the related `color` property and override it with `!important`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use **Firebug or Safari (or Chrome) inspector** to find out how divs are embedded in the DOM.

Here is what I have if I inspect the title of a titlebar

You can see a div with a `my-titlebar` class which contain another one with the class `x-title`. If you look on the right you can see that the color attribute is carried by the `x-title` CSS class. Therefore you need to override this class and NOT add a color attribute to another class.

[image]

So here's what you should do :

**Add a cls property to your titlebar**

```
xtype: 'titlebar',
cls:'my-titlebar',
docked: 'top',
height: 120,
```

**Write the CSS**

```
.my-titlebar .x-title{
  color:white;
}
```

And here you go :

[image]

Last advice, you should use `!important` only when you have no choice. Otherwise it makes no sense.

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 for this and -1 for my laziness LOL, just want to comment something to help him out but maybe something more specific like this is more useful

Comment: At first, I thought it was a bit of an exaggerated answer for such an easy question, but then I realized that teaching best practices and giving some tips is the way to go when you answer a question. So thank you.